# Save live video stream .m3u8 to MP4. Video freezes for a few seconds

Tags: video, ffmpeg, freeze, mp4, m3u8

I am trying to save in MP4 an .m3u8 live stream using FFMPEG.

The version in use is the following: ~ $ ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1 ~ 18.04)

While the command used for saving the stream in MP4 is the the one below:

ffmpeg -y -i https://stream.m3u8 --map 0 --vcodec copy -acodec copy ~ / output.mp4

The file can be successfully opened and played with VLC even though every 3-5 seconds I see that the video freezes every few seconds.

I wonder if it's something that I am missing in the above command.

I also verified whether the issue was related to the connection in use but it does not seem related.

Comment: Upgrade to 4.3 and check.